Android 11, Get a list of files inside the app specific folder in the external removable SDCard (storage/<CARD-ID>/Android/data/<APP-ID>/files)
I have a use case to get and verify a list of files inside the folder storage/CARD-ID/Android/data/APP-ID/files. The folder is created and deployed by the user with a PC.
The folder has the correct ID name of the application.
The issue is that the function listFiles() returns null.
The app can

Create a file inside the folder

Read a file from the folder by specifying its name

The app can't get a list of files!
    File [] storage = getExternalFilesDirs(null);
    File removableSdCardAppFolder = storage[1];
    File nf = new File(removableSdCardAppFolder, "output.txt");
    if(!nf.exists()){
        try {
            nf.createNewFile();/// Create the file
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    **File[] files = removableSdCardAppFolder.listFiles();//=null**

    DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromFile(removableSdCardAppFolder);
    **DocumentFile[] files2 = documentFile.listFiles();//=null**

    readTextFile(new File(removableSdCardAppFolder, "output.txt"));//Print the file content



App approved permissions:
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

